# Excel import fail without MS Office in windows application

Tags: .net, excel, ms-office, windows-forms-designer

I've a .net windows application running on Visual studio wherein I am uploading an excel sheet and manipulating some data.
I've just got a brand new notebook on which only MS word ***(Edit: MS word as well as MS Excel)*** viewer is installed(No MS Office installed yet). When I try to upload the excel sheet and was expecting the data to display it is not doing so.

Does the reason be not having MS Office installed on the machine?? However the application is having reference to Interop.Excel dll.

Comment: Did you install the interop dll ?

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you would need to have the Excel Viewer installed.  Depending on what you're doing, you may need an acutal Excel install.

Comment: Hi MrBlue, I've already have all the viewers viz., MS Word, Excel, Powerpoint. But in vain. My application has option to upload csv apart from .xls/.xlsx . So I tried uploadin .csv file and the app is running smooth. but not running with excel sheet.

Comment: If you have the Excel viewer installed and it's still not working then (without seeing any code) that implies you'll need an actual Office/Excel install to get it going.